# npm install fail -- error message: enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: npm, npm-install

i'm building an Vue.js project using `vue init webpack project_name`,after this step I ran `npm install`. and npm threw out errors below:

```
npm ERR! path /Users/duodian/Desktop/crop-demo/node_modules/js-
beautify/js/bin/css-beautify.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 
'/Users/duodian/Desktop/crop-demo/node_modules/js-beautify/js/bin/css-beautify.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/duodian/.npm/_logs/2017-09-18T09_55_20_047Z-debug.log
```

node version 8.5.0 
npm version  5.3.0 
**Note: I just updated my macOS HighSierra to 10.13 Beta, does this affect?**

had any friends have this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running

```
npm install js-beautify@1.6.14
```

and then

```
npm install (assuming that you are installing deps in package.json)
```

worked for me. Got it from here.
https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/1247

Answer (score 1):

It's bacause of js-beautify@1.7 i broken. So, try to downgrade vue-cli to 2.7.0 is a temporary workaround to solving this problem

```
npm install -g vue-cli@2.7.0
```